# Transfer data from PC application to remotely hosted  database

Tags: php, python, mysql, wxpython, data-transfer

Basically I want to be able to transfer data from PC application to remotely hosted database.

I have developed a wxPython which application which is used for parsing and analysing test data.

I want to update the application so that it can transfer the analysed data to an online MySQL database.

As it is for just for in house use by about a dozen individuals it doesn't need to be ultra robust, just a simple solution that works.

I dont have much experience on server side stuff so Im not really sure how this would usually be done, I know that directly connecting to the database from the app is not possible  due to security restrictions. Im thinking the I could use `ftplib` to upload the data as files and then call a `PHP`  script (to insert the data in the db)with `urllib2`. 
Will this work?

Comment: Are the security restrictions because of the MySQL server or where the application is running? Related: [MySQLdb through proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027751/mysqldb-through-proxy)

Comment: Restrictions are due to the web host.

Comment: I think there are no best approaches, I think it would help your question if you provided more specifics about your situation.

Comment: @Trufa: Could you be a bit more specific as to the specifics I should provide? I included everything that I thought was relevant, but as I mentioned Im not that experienced in this area so..

Comment: @volting: Sorry, I don't have much technical knowledge about this, so I can't be more specific (and BTW sorry if it sounded aggressive, it was not meant like that). I do think that in programming there is always thousands of ways to do the same thing and none are necessarily better that the other, only better suited. I think in order to get a better answer you might want to give as much background as you possible can in order for people to "easily" answer your question. I may be wrong given that I don't have too much experience in what you are asking, just a though about the question itself :)

Comment: Yes your right there can be dozens of ways to get things done, Im neither looking for the "best" or the most efficient just something that will work, and be fairly quick to code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have access server side? If so, you could enable secured remote mysql, or add a php page that allows access. For example, Python could use urllib to open "mypage/search.php?name=name&otherdata=otherdata", and read the result. This would also work in a web browser.

It seems uploading the file and then calling a script to run would be a bit inefficient and less secure, and would require access to the server. Why not have secure remote access for the database?

I'd look into some Python Mysql examples, if there is a possibility of setting up Mysql connections:
http://www.kitebird.com/articles/pydbapi.html

First get it working in a small example script, then you can paste the code into your project.

Comment: Im not too worried about efficiency, -this may only be used for only a few weeks to months so  I just need to something quick to implement and that will work without any glitches. I cant remotely connect to the database due to hosting restrictions. Im interested in your first idea, using urlib to open mypage/search.php.... could you show an example of a script like this?

Comment: Search the Python urllib documentation pages for GET and POST requests, when you open the url they will be sent to the PHP page's $_GET or $_POST variable, if PHP has access to the db then you can modify the db from there.

Comment: Yes ofcourse PHP has access to the database,  if I can do it with a POST request then this is the solution for me, I hadn't really considered this as I thought It wouldn't be possible to to send a large amount of data this way -Thanks

Comment: According to this, max post request is an option in php config file http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/9457.htm